# How to move members within a class in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

My question is really simple. I want to move some member from the top of the class to the bottom to leave the main method first. When I copy and paste it, I get the "class,interface expected" error. Is there a way to do this in Netbeans without copying and pasting?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you share the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your brackets {}. What you're doing is completely allowed, you are probably just putting it outside the class?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right. That was my mistake. Do you know if there is a way to do this without copying and pasting?

Comment: I don't think so. What helps though is if you click on an open bracket "{", it should highlight the closing bracket. This will make it easier to see where you should move it.

Answer (score 0):

Select your class files and right-click. There you can see Refactor row in refactor you can see move option. Select the directory and refactor it.